# Why the textbox is printed "3-" instead "-3"?

Tags: c#

when I want to take action, for example, 12-15 in my "Calculator" application, the result in textBox displays "3-" instead of "-3".

```
private void Button_equal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            liczba2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
            label1.Text = String.Empty;
            switch(dzialanie)
            {
                case 1:
                    textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(liczba1+liczba2);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(12-15);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(liczba1*liczba2);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(liczba1/liczba2);
                    break;
            }
            dzialanie = 0;
            startNewNumber = true;
        }
```

The result should display "-3" in the textBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your TextBox `RightToLeft` Property is set to `No`.

Comment: Thanks! I set `RightToLeft` on `Yes` instead `TextAlign` on `Right`.